# Using a derived key for CMAC

Tags: encryption, mac, key-derivation, authenticated-encryption

Consider the following authenticate-and-encrypt scheme that uses AES-128 in CBC mode for encryption and AES-128 - based CMAC for authentication:

1. Two keys are derived from the master key k (16 byte): `SHA256(k) = k1 || k2` (k1 and k2 are each 16 byte long)
2. The plaintext x is encrypted using AES-128 and key k1: `E_k1(x) = c`
3. The CMAC is computed using AES-128 and key k2: `CMAC_k2(x) = m`
4. The result is the concatenation of the ciphertext and the MAC: `c||m`

We are asked to use this method and I am wondering if there are any problems with deriving the keys for the encryption and the MAC using SHA256 hash?

(I am aware of the discussion around authenticate-then-encrypt vs. encrypt-then-authenticate vs. authenticate-and-encrypt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason why that would not be secure.  If you want to play it safe, though, you could always go with a standardized [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), such as [HKDF (RFC 5869)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) or one of the other KDFs listed in [this draft standard](http://wiki.tools.ietf.org/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-kdf-uses-00).  (The draft itself seems to be expired, but it's the most convenient list of standardized key derivation functions I could find.)

Comment: In contexts where [DPA](http://www.cryptography.com/public/pdf/DPATechInfo.pdf) or other side channel attacks are to be feared (Smart Cards, HSMs), there might be an issue with HMAC, or any other algorithm where secrets are hashed: the implementation of a the hash might not be designed/certified for side-channel resistance, when block ciphers typically are. This sometime is a reason to prefer block-cipher based KDF.

Comment: +1 and good links for KDFs. Another one is [this](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoKDFs.html).