# Is it safe to AES-CBC and AES-CMAC both using the same key?

Tags: aes, cmac

There is a very similar question ([Using a derived key for CMAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/using-a-derived-key-for-cmac)) but it doesn't quite answer this one (at least for me it does not).

I have a situation where I need to transfer some data. My data has variable length (but padded to 16-byte blocks, of course) and I encrypt it using AES-128 in CBC mode. It is done like this:

1. **I first prepend the data with last 16 bytes of previous ciphertext I sent out**, append data if it needs to round to 16 byte block, and then finally encrypt it. Therefore my plaintext looks like this: *[random_16_bytes_as_IV] [DATA] [PADDING]*
2. Then I calculate AES-CMAC over the entire ciphertext (**using the same key used for encryption**) and append it to the ciphertext and finally transmit to the receiver. So my transmission looks like this: *[CIPHERTEXT] [CMAC]*
3. Receiver receives, verifies the AES-CMAC, decrypts and discards first 16 bytes of IV and whatever was appended for 16-byte block padding.

A while ago it was suggested to me to use AES in CBC mode along with CMAC for a pet-project I am working on ([Is this an acceptable implementation of ARC4 encryption for my system?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14926/is-this-an-acceptable-implementation-of-arc4-encryption-for-my-system)) and now I wanted to check if this is the right way to do it. Even though it is a pet-project I should at least give my best to do it correctly.

My concerns are **bolded** above. Also, please note that those 16 bytes that I prepend are actually the AES-CMAC of preious transmission, maybe I should not use **those** 16 bytes but use the last 16 bytes of actual ciphertext instead? - or it doesn't matter since they are both known from previous transmission...

Comment: Why does `IV` go into the plaintext? $\;$

Comment: From my understanding, the receiving side needs to know the IV used for encryption. Since I don't know how to tell receiver what IV was used to encrypt, he would not be able to decrypt properly. That's why I add these 16 bytes to plaintext to always get different ciphertext after encrypting, and fix the actual IV of AES algorithm to all zeroes.

Comment: ... Just [concatenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the IV with the rest of the ciphertext. $\;$

Comment: Hm, OK I will make that change. After that, is everything else safe, the rest of the method? Am I giving away some information by using the same key for AES-CBC encryption and AES-CMAC?

Comment: Having said that, I'm now wondering if maybe your approach is more secure than the usual one. $\hspace{.6 in}$

Comment: OK then I will leave it as is. I still don't know if the method I used to complete the entire process of encryption and signing is valid and safe. :(

Comment: I don't know if it's safe to AES-CBC and AES-CMAC both using the same key.But I'm sure the way you chose IV with predictablity is definnetely not satisify CPA secure.more info see [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/why-is-cbc-with-predictable-iv-considered-insecure-against-cpa/)

Comment: @binta I did think this too, but the effective IV here is not the predictable "last 16 bytes of previous ciphertext", but the AES-encryption of those, which should not be predictable by an attacker, assuming no time-rollback.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann yes,you are right."please note that those 16 bytes that I prepend are actually the AES-CMAC of preious transmission"oh, my poor english...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple.
The recommandations of all experts in this case is to dissociate Keys used for Encryption from Keys used for MAC-ing.
Then you have to use two different Keys.

Comment: I will accept this answer simply because said above is correct, even though it doesn't answer all my questions. Thanks.